# Using a monolog logger within the Slim microframework, there are no errors being output however no log files are being created or written to

Tags: php, slim, monolog

I have used Monologing before and not had a problem however with this application no log files are being created even though I have monolog warnings and notices throughout the application but nothing has been created, It might also be worth noting that I have session variables created but session files in the "var" file however I am not sure if that is the same issue. I am using xampp as my development environment.

No errors have been output and I have var_dump the logger to make sure it has been created properly and there does not seem to be an issue there.

Here is the file structure:

[image: 'file structure']

Any help would be appreciated

```
     /* Settings file */
     // Get log file path
     $log_file_path = '/Football_Trivia_Game/logs/';
     // Define log file path
     define('LOG_FILE_PATH', $log_file_path);
```

```
    /* Dependencies.php */
    use Monolog\Logger;
    use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
    use Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler;

    // Create container for two different kind of loggers
    // One logger will handles notices and the other handles warning
    $container['logger'] = function() {
    // Instantiate logger
    $logger = new Logger('logger');

    // Notices logger
    // Set notices log path
    $notices_log = LOG_FILE_PATH . 'notices.log';
    // Create stream handler for notices logger
    $stream_notices = new StreamHandler($notices_log, Logger::NOTICE);
    // Push stream handler into logger object
    $logger->pushHandler($stream_notices);

    // Warning logger
    // Set warning log path
    $warning_log = LOG_FILE_PATH . 'warnings.log';
    // Create stream handler for warnings logger
    $stream_warnings = new StreamHandler($warning_log, Logger::WARNING);
    // Push stream handler into logger object
    $logger->pushHandler($stream_warnings);

    $logger->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
        $record['context']['sid'] = session_id();
        return $record;
    });

    // Return looger
    return $logger;
    };
```

```
        /* This is an example of an attempt to use the logger in the database connection /*
        try {
            $pdo_handle = new \PDO($host_details, $username, $password, $pdo_attributes);
            $this->db_handle = $pdo_handle;
            $this->logger->notice("Connected to database successfully!");
         }
         catch(\PDOException $exception_object) {
            trigger_error('Error connection to the database');
            $pdo_error = 'Error connection to the database';
            $this->logger->warning("Failed to connect to database!");
         }
```

Comment: Do i get it right that even if you write `$this->logger->notice("Test message");`  without any conditions it doesn't write anything either?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes this is correct, if I run a test with no conditions nothing happens, it does not write anything and does not output an error.